# Count below a comment is misleading

Tags: bug, comments

When you are writing a comment, type something with 14 characters. It will tell you that you need one more at least. Leave a space. It will look like you can post the comment. Try posting it, it says you can't. But according to the counter just below the text-area, you should be fine.

Comment: because they are trimming the text?

Comment: @DarthVader Still..

Comment: Still what? if they dont trim the text, u can put 15 empty space.

Comment: Still, it is a bug.

Comment: no it s not. why would it be bug?

Comment: Ok whatever, if you say so..

Comment: put 15 space and try to submit.

Answer (score 3):

The message showing the number of characters that are still necessary to reach the minimum comment length, or the number of characters that you can still type is shown on browser side, while the validation of the comment is done server-side.

The error message could be changed as the following, but then it should list all the characters that are removed.

> Comments must be at least 15 characters in length. Trailing spaces are removed.

For example, 15 spaces followed by a back-tick still cause the error to appear.

Probably the message should be similar to the following one, if it needs to really be changed.

> Comments must be at least 15 characters in length. Some characters are not considered when calculating the comment lenght.

Comment: Surely javascript has a :strip" function that can be applied before the "count" function - so that it will accurately determine the *real* allowed character length?

Comment: It is more complicated than removing some characters from the end of the comment. Plus, parsing the comment is done server-side.